# Dockware admin watcher page often hangs/freezes in browser

Tags: docker, webpack-dev-server, shopware, shopware6

We have a problem that at some point nothing works in the browser when we use the admin watcher from a Dockware container.
The page stops loading after a while, requests are all stalled as pending and nothing happens when opening the page in a new tab.
If you open the page in another browser at the same time, it works perfectly, without any delay, of course only for a while.
What I have noticed so far is that it works a little better in Firefox than in Chromium browsers.

Are there perhaps too many requests from a browser for Docker/Node?
Do the browsers perhaps have problems because of the hostname resolution (localhost)?

We also have this problem with the admin watcher of the shopware-cli

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything about this, and they couldn't help me in the Community Slack either.
Maybe someone knows the problem and has a solution?

Comment: I have noticed a very similar problem in a custom developer environment. E.g. On our test servers and perhaps also in my custom Docker setup. Don't remember the specifics.

What I noticed in, at least in our case, it had to do with misconfigured CORS policy. Initially everything would be working fine, but suddenly I would get "blocked by client" errors in the console lock, and indeed also, possibly unrelated, 500 errors on occasion.

Try adjusting your `content-security-policy` header, and also, check in shopware/var/log/* for potential logged errors.